# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send' when trying to send embeds using discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Trying to use discord.py and learning the beginnings of bot developement, but when I try to send an embed, it gives me the error.

I tried:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="title", color=0x13fa07)
        embed.add_field(name="name1", value="value1", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="name2", value="value2", inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="bot test 0.1")
        await message.send(embed=embed)
        
client.run('token here')
```

(token ofc censored)

but then it returns

`AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to discord.py, just as the error says `'Message' object has no attribute 'send'` but it does have the attribute `channel` which has the method `send` that you are looking for [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message)

```
...
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```